# Scraping - How to get a value of a dynamically generated content?

Tags: web-crawler, screen-scraping

I'm inspecting a website using `Firefox firebug tool`. This is intended for scraping. I want to get the value of the dynamically generated content.

I understood how the site works, but I'm stuck at a specific(final) point. Need help from the experienced people out here.

Ultimate motive is to get the link of the product:-

**Step1)** It searches for a product(in the search bar) using its API. The input to this API is `product name` and the response is the search results in the form of HTML content, and finally displays the result on the page.

**Step2)** To get a link of a selected product, the website hits another API with the above `uniqueID` of the product, and the response(link) is of the form `http://example.com/uniqueId/?link_id={{link_id}}`

The above response is displayed in the textbox along with the proper `link_id`, not `{{link_id}}`.

Upon inspecting(using firebug) the textbox, the content inside is `http://example.com/uniqueId/?link_id={{link_id}}`. However, when seen on the front-end, it displays `http://example.com/uniqueId/?link_id=123bad3`

Not sure but I feel, this is similar to Jinja template language, where `{{link_id}}` is a context variable and is server-populated.

**How can I extract the `link_id`?**

Comment: which technologies (languages and frameworks) are you using to scrape websites?

Comment: Python. Beautiful Soup.

Comment: i'm not too familiar with beautiful soup, but are you sure it can scrape dynamically generated content? you could try using something like Selenium or Splash or Chrome's headless browser?

Comment: I'm not dependent on technology. However, I just want the logic behind this. How can I extract the `link_id`.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you're going to have to use some sort of "web driver" technology to follow the link in order to retrieve the `uniqueID`, so that you can programatically reconstruct the links yourself. I don't believe there's any way around this.

Comment: am i misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Let me give a try with Selenium(Python) and I'll come back by EOD. In the meantime, I'm open for other suggestions too.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast EOD? are you using Python 3 or 2 or does it even matter?

Comment: EOD = end of day. I'm using Python3. No, it should not matter. Since, I'm versed with Python, hence using the same.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast I may be in bed, but i'll check back in probably no later than 24 hours. GL!

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast well, any luck?